# how does a jet engine work? (explanation for non-aviation related people)

Tags: jet-engine

Which day-to-day example would you use to explain a person (who is not involved into the aviation sector) how does a jet engine work? Would objects such as a hairdryer, a vacuum cleaner or a fan be appropriate?

Comment: Blow up a balloon and let go. Air rushes out of the back. Newton tells us that every action has an equal and opposite reaction; the balloon goes the other way. How does a jet engine get air to rush out of the back?  It compresses it, injects fuel and burns it.  It burns very quickly and expands.  The only place it can expand it out of the back so it rushes out of there are the jet goes in the opposite direction.  A jet engine is just another internal combustion engine using [suck, squeeze, bang, blow](http://jalopnik.com/suck-squeeze-bang-blow-ge-explains-how-a-jet-engin-1593409462)

Comment: I posted an additional answer specifically for you [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/how-do-jet-engines-work#answer-32273). This answer is in very simple words, but accurate. To me this question should not be closed, it targets a different level of explanation than the duplicate.

Comment: I vote for leaving this question closed. If the existing answers of a question are not "simple enough", then new answers (or edits) should be added to address a wider audience.

Comment: @kevin: Which principle of SE are you referring to?

Comment: @mins generally we have a few answers to a question, and sometimes a "TL;DR" section and a detailed section within the same answer. That's my impression anyway - questions are based on topics, not audience levels.

Comment: @kevin. In this case, the OP question is mentioning a "*day-to-day example*" and is asking (maybe more) for an explanation of the reaction principle that is not found at all in the "duplicate".