# Is axial bearing in turbo fan,turbo jet engines neutraly loaded?

Tags: turbofan, thrust, turbojet

Is axial bearing in turbo fan,turbo jet engines neutraly loaded,if yes then turbine/fan and compresor produce eqaul and opposite force?

If yes ,where then thrust come from,at internal walls,must be some pressure net force to produce thrust.

Comment: See: [On which point(s) in a jet engine does the reaction force act?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33068/3201)

Comment: @mins thanks nice explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it generally is not neutral. There is usually some net force. The reason is that very low force is actually bad for bearing life. Look up skidding. So a small imbalance in forces between compressor and turbine is introduced intentionally