# Why are there curved blades on jet engines?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine, compressor

On the fan and comssorssor and turbine for that matter there are blades and they are also curved. Im already confused beucase the fan has blades but wouldn't it blow out air not suck in air? Why are there blades even on the compressor and turbine and why are they curved?

Comment: Are you asking why they're curved specifically (which involves aerodynamics) or why they're there at all (which would imply a question about how a jet engine actually works)?

Comment: *"fan has blades but wouldn't it blow out air not suck in air"*... One side of the fan sucks, the other side blows. If you were standing behind the fan, it would be blowing... Same with household fans, spray a mist behind the fan and you'll see it sucks air in and blows it out the other side.

Comment: What do you mean by curved? Are you referring to the twist that each blade has from the root to the tip where the angle at the root is greater than the angle at the tip of the blade? Or are you referring to the curve of the blade that makes it look like a little wing--the camber of the blade?

Comment: @RonBeyer but like a household fan if I spray a mist in front of it it will be blown away so I get confused by the fan of an aircraft, wouldn't it blow air away from it, why does it get sucked in and not blown out?

Comment: @Itzyoboi I'm not sure how else I can explain it, one side of the fan sucks, the other side blows. They mounted the fan such that the "blow" side is towards the engine, which means that when you look at the engine, you are looking at the "suck" side. If you could stand on the other side of the fan (inside the engine) you would feel quite a wind blowing at you from the fan...

Comment: @RonBeyer I see. So why are there blades on the compressor, does it help create heat by causing more collusion with air molecules beucase it's spinning ? Does it help the same just blows the air faster?

Comment: The compressor uses blades to compress the air, the fan on the front doesn't really compress it. Heat is a side-effect of compressing a gas. See [How do jet engines work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/how-do-jet-engines-work).

Comment: @RonBeyer what is the need of blades on the compressor if the fan is blowing air through a small duct channel which gets smaller?

Comment: You should look up how the compressor stages work, I really can't explain it in the comments of an unrelated question.

Comment: @RonBeyer ok and is the shape of the fan and foward swept tips why the big front fans suck and not blow? Last question, and thanks.

Comment: No, the forward swept tips deal with the efficiency of the fan, if you wanted the fan to blow out the front, all you would have to do is run the engine in reverse. Same with your home fan too, you can make it blow out the back and suck in the front if you could reverse it

Comment: @RonBeyer so no one really knows why the fan sucks insteads of blow. You said it was the position, how would that effect it? Or does it suck becuase that's just how it works

Comment: Yes, they know **exactly** why it sucks instead of blows. Same reason propellors blow backwards, *it's designed to do that*. It deal with the angle of the blade and the direction of rotation.