# How does a rotary piston (radial) engine work?

Tags: piston-engine

How does a Gnome rotary piston engine work?  I would like to see how it works in detail, possibly with text explanation.

Comment: http://www.animatedengines.com/gnome.html

Comment: Do you mean a rotary piston engine as fitted to early aircraft (like the [Gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_Monosoupape)), or the [Wankel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine) rotary engine?

Comment: Yes..thank you..I mean like Gnome engine

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_engine) has a couple of animations. Are they "good"? If not, what's wrong with them?

Comment: For the people voting this as off-topic, what about [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2772/62)?

Comment: Asking how something works can be on-topic.  Asking for an external resource is usually off-topic on most (all?) SE sites.

Comment: http://enginehistory.org/Piston/Before1925/Rotaries/GnomeMonosoupape.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Link from @Gerry 's comment: http://www.animatedengines.com/gnome.html

Short version: take a radial and attach the output shaft to the aircraft firewall/structure.  Feed the intake through the shaft, let the exhaust go where it goes.  Fasten the propeller to the crankcase.

These engines were usually lubricated by mixing oil in the fuel, and passing the intake charge through the crankcase (similar to a modern 2-stroke engine, though without the pressurized crankcase).  Spark was produced by a fixed magneto and distributed to the plugs by a gap contact similar to that in an old style auto distributor.

Many of these engines had no effective throttle, or could only throttle a little (35%, maybe even 50% minimum power).  If you see an air show with an original or repro aircraft using the correct engine, you'll hear them blipping the ignition off and back on during landing approach, as that's the only way to reduce power sufficiently to land.

Comment: The oil for lubrication was usually castor oil, which explains the elaborate scarfs worn by many pilots. Failing to put those over your mouth during flight meant that you would spend hours on the loo after landing.